# Can't figure out why node + physics body is not responding to gravity or impulses

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've created a subclass for a certain type of node, which is called TargetNode. Here's what that looks like, and how I've defined the PhysicsBody for that subclass.

```
class TargetNode: SKSpriteNode, CustomNodeEvents {
   func didMoveToScene() {
     isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
     physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
     physicsBody!.restitution = 1.0
     physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
     physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
   }
}
```

Then, in the scene, I try and add that to the scene (it's a game).

```
let name = createTarget()
let targetNode = TargetNode(imageNamed: name)
targetNode.didMoveToScene() // added this after question below
targetNode.name = name
fgNode.addChild(targetNode)
chickenNodes.append(targetNode)
targetNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 0)
targetNode.position = generateZoneAndPoint()
```

However, the node is not responding to gravity, even though I've defined the PhysicsWorld, etc., for the scene:

```
let playableRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: playableRect)
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

It also isn't responding to any kind of impulse that I apply to it. Why is this the case? What do I need to adjust or change?

EDIT: I also called these nodes previously... the code for that was:

```
enumerateChildNodes(withName: "*//*, using: { node, _ in
  if let customNode = node as? CustomNodeEvents {
     customNode.didMoveToScene()
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you show us where in your code you are calling your subclass's didMoveToScene method? That is not a method of SKSpriteNode so presumably something to do with your CustomNodeEvents protocol/extension?

Comment: I don't believe you make this mistake but reading your question seems you've confused init methods of your custom class `TargetNode` with `didMoveToScene`, in other words seems you'ven't call `didMoveToScene` method like you think that's happened automatically. Maybe you've simply forgot to call this method..and the `SKPhysicsBody` is not created..

Comment: @AliBeadle i have a separate file which defines the protocol for CustomNodeEvents. I can see the physics body has been added, though, when I view the physics simulations in View Controller, but they won't respond to impulses or gravity.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano See above!

Comment: But **when** is didMoveToScene being called? E.g. you are trying to access its physics body soon after creating it and adding it to your node tree - are you *sure* didMoveToScene is being called before then? If not then physicsBody will still be null and physicsBody?.XXX will do nothing, even if physicsBody does *later* exist.

Comment: Actually, I did call this explicitly. See edit.

Comment: What's strange is that I can control whether the body is dynamic or not using this code. But it doesn't respond to gravity or impulses.

Comment: Can you tell us what fgNode is?

Comment: It's just a node that is the parent node to all the child nodes in the scene. It is defined earlier in the code as var fgNode = SKNode()

Comment: Possibly not the problem but: it is a bit odd to have a node with a physics body be a child of another node in the scene. Is this necessary for your functionality? If not does adding the node directly to the scene change its behaviour?

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint to a reasonable point of your scene, and after, try to analyze from the debug console what kind of bodies are connected to your physicsWorld, if these bodies are defined as rectangles etc...you can look at the left of your debug console the tree SELF->nameOfYourScene->SpriteKit-SKScene->_physicWorld->_bodies

Comment: @amalfilemons So you see the node and its physics body, right? Just want to confirm that... Because I used your code and everything works fine for me (I made an appropriate protocol, initialized TargetNode with a spaceship image).

Comment: @Whirlwind Yep, I see the node and I see the blue outline. It just doesn't respond to gravity or anything else.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I'll try the breakpoint in a bit and revert to you. Thanks for the help.